# How to return a file from akka get route in java

Tags: java, get, akka, akka-http

I want to send a file in response to a client's request. I need the code for the route to send a file in response. I want to build route using akka in java.

```java
public Route createRoute() {
        return concat(get(()->
                path("getVideo",() -> {
                    return complete("return video file here");
                })));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [getFromFile](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/file-and-resource-directives/getFromFile.html) directive.

So something like the following should work:

```
public Route createRoute() {
    return concat(get(()->
            path("getVideo",() -> {
                return getFromFile("/path/to/file");
            })));
}
```